# WCF connectionstring from configuration file with EF6

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, configuration-files

I've a WCF service with an internal connectionString "Model_DB_Custom" to connect to my database with Entity Framework 6.

DBContext constructor is:

```
public partial class Model_DB : DbContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a dbcontext from default connectionString in app.config to Sql Server
        /// </summary>
        public Model_DB() : base(
            ((ConnectionStringsSection)
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
                    .GetSection("connectionStrings"))
                    .ConnectionStrings["Model_DB_Custom"]
                    .ConnectionString)
        {
            //This constructor works if connectionstring is changed at runtime...
        }

...
}
```

When a windows service application use this WCF service, `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)` returns correct WCF server config file (means `"C:\Program Files\WCfService\WCfService.exe.config"`)

When a WPF application use this WCF service, , `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)` returns its config file (means `"C:\Program Files\WPFApp\WPFApp.exe.config"`)

Some ideas I have:

- Permission issue? Windows Service is running under System Account and
  WPF application under an administrator.
- Bad app.config file for these 2 clients?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just use:  base("name=Model_DB_Custom")

Comment: Hi Eric, this solution doesn't seem to work if this connection string is modified at WCF Service runtime...

Comment: In fact, base("name=Model_DB_Custom") is not recognized. I try but I can see that database connection is: "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true". I suppose it's a default connectionstring... I've never implemented that.

Comment: Based on your comments, it doesn't seem like you're actually calling your WCF service remotely, but rather directly referencing the service implementation and running it in-process. Are we missing something here?

Comment: @thomasr, thanks for your interesting comment! I ve added a reference of wcf service library in every client. I dont use kind of proxy because it worked with my windows service. Are you talking of using"svcutil" before wcf service use?

Comment: In fact, I'm using ChannelFactory() method so, as far as I know, proxies are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas, you were right! Thanks for this good idea!

Ok, finally my issue was not related at all to app.config(s).

I didn't call correctly my WCF service.

To avoid proxies generation/use, I use ChannelFactory() in my WCF Service because I manage both servers and clients and that was this SimpleIOC configuration which was bad...

Now this WCF Service is implemented throw MVVM Light/SimpleIOC with following code:

ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            //Define data access (wcf service) for design mode
            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            ...
    }
```

WcfServer class:

```
public class WcfServer : IDisposable
    {
        ...
        //Wcf connection
        private ChannelFactory<IService> _wcfFactory = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the DataService proxy from MVVMLight SimpleIOC instance.
        /// </summary>
        public IService DataService
        {
            get
            {
                return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IService>();
            }
        }

        public WcfServer(string urlServer)
        {
            UrlServer = urlServer;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connect to wcf service
        /// </summary>
        public bool Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                ...

                EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(UrlServer));
                if (_wcfFactory == null)
                {
                    _wcfFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(WCFSharedConfiguration.ConfigureBindingWithSimplehttps(), endpointAddress);

                    //Open ChannelFactory
                    _wcfFactory.Open();

                    //Define Faulted handler
                    _wcfFactory.Faulted += FactoryFaulted;
                }
                else
                    //Log + return

                if (!ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
                {
                    //If we are not in Design (means blend or VS IDE)
                    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IService>(() => _wcfFactory.CreateChannel(), true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log
                throw;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool Disconnect()
        {
              SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<IService>();
        }
   }
```

May it helps!